# Черепицею шурша...

Tags: орфография

Думаю, этот стишок знают все: "Черепицею шурша, крыша едет не()спеша". Однако встает вопрос: а как пишется в данном случае слово "не()спеша": слитно или раздельно? То есть, мы тут имеем дело с наречием или с деепричастным оборотом? Либо, может быть, тут вообще уместны оба варианта?
Хотя интуитивно я бы написала слитно: "неспеша" - так логичнее по контексту.

Comment: В моём детстве крыша шуршала шифером.

>Тихо шифером шурша,  
Едет крыша не спеша.

Comment: +1 @Яzz

Про черепицу слышать лично мне не приходилось. А про шифер знаю в таком варианте:

*Едет крыша не спеша  
Тихо шифером шурша*

Answer (score 3):

ПРАВИЛЬНО: Черепицею шурша, крыша едет не спеша.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Если наречие образовано от деепричастия, то оно, как правило, сохраняет раздельную форму написания  (хотя при этом наречие можно заменить синонимом без НЕ и оно не выделяется запятыми, как деепричастие): рассердиться не шутя (всерьёз), идти не спеша (тихо), ехать не торопясь (медленно),  отправиться не мешкая (сейчас), жить ни с кем не знакомясь (замкнуто), выйти замуж не любя (без любви).

Слитное написание НЕ с наречиями, образованными от деепричастий, возможно в единичных случаях, которые рассматриваются как словарные  варианты: делать все НЕХОТЯ.

Следует запомнить  парный вариант со слитным и раздельным написанием НЕ: Выехать НЕМЕДЛЯ (сейчас же),  НЕ МЕДЛЯ НИ МИНУТЫ  (устойчивое выражение).